# How to throw a validation error in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Without using any JavaScript library like JQuery, how do I show an error to the user if the title of the Post exceeds 40 characters? I would like to use WordPress API/ PHP for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is submitted, check the length of the request parameter and return an error when it's too long.